# generating dates corresponding to weekdays in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Hello I have this code in python

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

date=pd.date_range(start="2019-01-04",end="2020-05-12")
```

This generates all dates from 2019-01-04 to 2020-05-12 but what I want is just week dates, (dates corresponding to week days. i.e. Monday to Friday). How can I do that? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `pd.bdate_range`

```
pd.bdate_range(start="2019-01-04",end="2020-05-12")
```